# How to match unicode character regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have the input and regex of

```
  const input = `iPhone Xʀ`;
  
  console.log(input.match(/^([\w\d\-\s]*)/));
```

I have not been able to figure out how to match the `ʀ` unicode character.

I tried `\\p{L}` as noted in another SO post.
Also tried putting `u` for unicode as a modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{L}` in conjunction with the flags `gu`:

```js
const input = `iPhone Xʀ`;
console.log(input.match(/^([\w\d\-\s]*\p{L})/gu));
  
// output:

// [
//  "iPhone Xʀ"
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. not using the `g` flag also worked

Comment: @RayJ_inSJ Happy to help. Regarding the `g` flag, if it's omitted, the resulting array has two entries, with it only one. Not sure if that makes a difference in your case but worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Please get the Unicode of the character and use the following pattern.

```
  const input = `iPhone Xʀ`;
  console.log(input.match(/^([\w\d\-\s]*)\x{0280}/));
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work as written, `null` is returned instead of an arrays of matches.